# where to put the arraylist.add method

Tags: android, url, imageview

MainActivity.java  @override onPostExecute method

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setText(moviesArray.get(0).getTitle());

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                String imageUrl= "http://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/node-cover-720x340.png";

                Bitmap bitmap = GetImageFromURL.getBitmap(imageUrl);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

GetImageFromURL.java

```
  public class GetImageFromURL {


        public static Bitmap getBitmap(String imgUrl){
            Bitmap b = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                 b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            }catch (Exception e){

            }

            return b;
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/im"/>
```

I want to display images from an url. But I dont know why the image not displaying and no error occurs. pls help!

Comment: You don't get any error because your `catch` bloc is empty, add `e.printStackTrace();` or `Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());`

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException meaning I should not write connection in onPostExecution?   should put in doInBackground?

Comment: That means you shouldn't do a connection on the UI thread so you must do it in `doInBackground()` (which executed on the background thread)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Mainpage extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView iv1
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpage);
        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        LoadImageFromURL task = new LoadImageFromURL();
        task.execute();
        }

    public class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/node-cover-720x340.png");
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                iv1.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
                return bitMap;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the different between doing it in doInBackground and onPostExecute

Comment: @Amir john:  I think `iv1.setImageBitmap(bitMap);` should be in `onPostExecute()` method ( `iv1.setImageBitmap(result);` )

Comment: i tried to put in doInBackground() i works...  I am think how to display dynamic images in doInBackground